# List available docker tags when creating a release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Backstory:
We have a web app that creates batch jobs in Azure using docker images. In the application configuration there is a parameter to defines which version of the docker image the batch job should use. In our current setup we need to manually change the parameter if we deploy a new version of the docker image.

What I want to do is choose which docker image to use when I create a release for the web app. I already have a working release pipeline where I manually type in which version of the docker image I want to use, but I would like to be able to choose from the available docker images in the repository. The docker images are built in Azure devops and we have a tag on each build with the version number.

Is it possible to achieve this?

[image: Current setup]